# bref.sh php container for AWS Lambda with Neos CMS

Tags: php, neoscms, bref, aws-lambda-containers

I'm struggling to get Neos (a php based cms) to run in a docker container for AWS Lambda.
I guess I have somewhere a misunderstanding and hope anyone can help.

What I did so far:

1. I adjusted Neos so that all cache files will be written to the tmp folder
2. I added the bref and extra-php-extensions package to composer.json
3. I created a docker file, quite simple as shown by Mattheu Naploli's blog article: https://mnapoli.fr/aws-lambda-php-docker-containers/
4. I have created a cloudformation template to use `sam local start-api`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bref/php-74-fpm

COPY . /var/task

# Start Bref's runtime client
CMD _HANDLER=Web/index.php /opt/bootstrap
```

template.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  neos-demo-lambda

  Sample SAM Template for neos-demo-lambda

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  Neos:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Show neos demo
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: neos7.demo.lambda.php74:latest
      #Handler: "Web/index.php /opt/bootstrap"
      #Handler: "Web/index.php"
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 360
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FLOW_CONTEXT: 'Production'
          FLOW_PATH_TEMPORARY_BASE: '/tmp/neos'
          FLOW_PATH_DATA_BASE: '/tmp/Data'
          BREF_AUTOLOAD_PATH: '/var/task/Packages/Libraries/autoload.php'
          AWS_S3_BUCKET_STORAGE: 'neos-lambda-demo-private'
          AWS_S3_BUCKET_TARGET: 'neos-lambda-demo-public'
          AWS_CLOUDFRONT_BASE_URI: ''
          AWS_REDIS_HOST: ''

      Events:
        htmlHttpApi:
          Type: HttpApi
          TimeoutInMillis: 28000

    Metadata:
      DockerTag: neos7.lambda.demo
      DockerContext: ./Web/index.php
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Response of `sam local start-api`:

```
entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
time="2021-04-14T22:11:48.093" level=error msg="Init failed" InvokeID= error="Runtime exited with error: exit status 142"
time="2021-04-14T22:11:48.093" level=error msg="INIT DONE failed: Runtime.ExitError"
Invalid lambda response received: Lambda response must be valid json
2021-04-15 00:11:48 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2021 00:11:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

What I don't understand, I'd expect that there is always a valid json returned, even though the php delivers a 5xx error.
I'm lost ... even though this wouldn't be the case, how can I debug the issue?

In the end, I have to create my own docker image as Neos is too big to use the bref layers and I need quite some php extensions.
If I could understand the current issue, I can work through this and provide a working container for everyone.

I have a few more questions, in this scenario, were I have a web application and use a container, do I have to install the bref packages with composer? That wasn't clear in the blog post. Also do I have to set the Handler in serverless/sam and if so, which would be the correct string, given that `Web/index.php` is the path in Neos?

In general, Neos would work awesome in AWS.
My setup would be:

1. CloudFront with behaviors for static files from S3 and everything else to lambda
2. Redis to store cache files from Neos
3. ElasticSearch for website search and improved performance on huge sites

As soon as this is working, I'll publish all information for free for the Neos community to get this working.

Hope someone can help...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this:

```
FROM bref/php-74-fpm

# Include any extension you want, for example:
#COPY --from=bref/extra-gd-php-74:0.9.5 /opt /opt

ADD . $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT

CMD [ "index.php" ]
```

The format has been simplified since the article (see https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/f911a50c7aab77690e6cdde157812265).

Comment: Thank you, I'm one step further! But get now an fpm error:  ALERT: [pool default] user has not been defined, ERROR: failed to post process the configuration, ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Error while starting PHP-FPM
Fatal error: Exception: PHP-FPM failed to start

Comment: @kapale - Did you manage to solve that php-fpm failed to start issue? I am stuck on the same issue..

Comment: @avijendr - unfortunately no. Its a problem on how Neos bootstrapping is working. There would be quite some refactoring of Neos necessary to make this work. One of the big problems - as far as I remember - is how and when folders and files are created. There are quite some limitations within a lambda. But it's too long ago.